# How to organize key-values to implement Redis ZSet commands by RocksDB?

Tags: key-value-store, sortedset, rocksdb, skip-lists

I implement Redis ZSet commands by RocksDB, and iterator is really slow with big key, how can I optimize these key-values?

I devide 1 zset key-element-score with 3 RocksDB key-values, such as `name2age:linda:25`

- **meta key:**

  `"name2age": 1`  // count one element, use for zcard
- **index key:**

  `"name2age:linda": 25`  // use for zrangebyindex
- **score key:**

  `"name2age:25:linda": NULL`  // use for zrangebyscore

```golang
// using rocksdb iterate to start index, count offset, and select elements
// this will be slow when zset have too many elements
```

I want a new implementation to rewrite zset, maybe some tips, thanks a lot

Comment: Are you still interested by the answer to this question? In what programming language do you want me to provide a solution?

Comment: Yes please, Golang would be best, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To implement a sorted set on top an ordered key-value store, you must rely on probabilistic datastructure called the [skip-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

**But in your question the operations that you want to perform do not require a skip list.**

See this slides for a intro on [skip-lists](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/skiplists.pdf)

And this [thread on foundationdb forums on how to implement a leaderboard](https://forums.foundationdb.org/t/how-to-model-a-leaderboard/373) which is most likely what you want.

This links to a C# implementation that can be found on [github](https://github.com/Doxense/foundationdb-dotnet-client/blob/master/FoundationDB.Layers.Common/Collections/FdbRankedSet.cs)

Good luck!